# Can we define $ℝ^A$ where A is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The question is pretty straightforward. How can we define the expression $ℝ^A$ when $A$ is an uncountable set?

For example what is defined by forms such as $ℝ^ℝ$ or $ℝ^ℂ$?

If $A$ is countable,then $A \sim ℕ$ and thus $A=[a_n:n=1,2,...]$ for $a_n$ such that $a_n\neq a_m$ if$n\neq m$ and $ℝ^A$ is linearly isomorphic to $ℝ^ℕ$ via $$ℝ^A∍f\rightarrow(f(a_n))_{n{\in \mathbb(N)}} \inℝ^ℕ$$
where$f$ is an isomorphism.

PS I suppose this is a topic more relevant to topology than real-analysis,but I am not sure,thus I tagged both.

Comment: I am used to think of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ as the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (and sets isomorphic to it), but there may be a more canonical answer.

Comment: The set of all functions $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has such a cardinal. So yes, we can!

Comment: I believe the correct tag for this question would be set theory.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Thanks Tim.I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ are sequences $(a_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}}$ where for each $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a designated element of $\mathbb{R}$, $a_\lambda$. Similarly for $\mathbb{C}$ and we could define this for any set $A$.

Another notion that is equivalent to the one above would be: given a set $A$, the set $\mathbb{R}^A$ is the set of all functions $f:A\rightarrow R$. You can check that this agrees with the above definitions.

Comment: So I guess it's a generalisation of sorts,off the countable case..Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Eoin: I wouldn't use the term `sequence` in such a case.

Comment: @Bernard: I would.

Comment: @AsafKaragila only if the domain is well-ordered I would use sequence.

Comment: @Henno: If you assume the axiom of choice, the domain is always well-ordered. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The set $\mathbf R^A$ is define like any other $B^A$: it is the set of maps from $A$ to $\,\mathbf R$. Its elements can be seen (and denoted) as a *family* of real numbers indexed by elements of $A$, i.e. instead of writing it $\,f\colon A\to\mathbf R$, one writes it as $\,(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bernard.Might be making a wild guess here,but can we,in the same manner,define any form $A^B$ as elements of $A$ indexed by elements of $B$?

Comment: More precisely as families of elements of $A$, indexed by the elements of $B$ (note an element of $A$ can be repeated).

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "power set".

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: You're right, it's confusing. I've modified my answer. Thanks for pointing  it.